# Rollback database changes if the client cancel the request

Tags: php, database, http, websocket

**Summary**:

I want to roll back database changes if the client cancels the request (closes his browser/tab, refreshes the page, etc..) before the response is returned.

**My Case:**

I'm creating a view in the backend, this view is very private, it's created on request and an entity in the database is created on every request, and saves dates when a user makes this view and when he leaves it.

I'm using WebSocket `onClose` to determine if the client closes his page, like the following:

1. Client makes an HTTP request to create the page.
2. The client waits for ~2 seconds until the page is created (some data are saved in the database about when this page is created, what it contains, etc ..).
3. The response is returned back to the client.
4. WebSocket then initialized.
5. Now if the client closes the page, WebSocket `onClose` will be triggered and indicate when the user left the page.

Everything works great! until I noticed that some clients view the page but never leave it! I investigate further and found out that they made the HTTP request to create the page, and they abounded that request before the response is returned, thus, the page is created but the WebSocket never initialized!

The solution that I thought of is to check if the user abounded the request before the response is returned, then database changes should roll back (is there a better solution?).

**Code Languages**

I am using PHP (Laravel) and MySql as a database.

Comment: This seems very timing-dependent, and thus unreliable. Why not save the partial details in the user session, and save to the database only when they finalize it?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yea I know, but couldn't find another way to do it, I need that entity to be created in the database whenever the user requests it, because other users can't request the same page until the current user is done from it (if the page is created and not finished yet, no one else can access that page until the end_at flag is not null)

Comment: Well, I don't know of any way to tell that the client has closed the browser mid-request. Can you wait on creating the record until the page is loaded and WebSocket created?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Actually great suggestion, maybe the only way is to create the page entity via WebSocket by JS when the user access the page and the WebSocket initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wait until the web socket is ready/initialized, then request the page via HTTP-Request and finaly render it.

However, in addition to your current solution use the *onbeforeunload* event like :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', abort, false);
function abort(e) {
   // code to abort 
   socket.close();   
}
```

With this event you capture closing a tab or the browser.